# Creating Mount Points

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive

Could somebody please help me? I'm rather new to Ubuntu and just trying to figure a few things out.

Just as an example, I have a program that writes a lot of log files to a folder called /var/logging/data123.

I'm running out of space, so i physically added a 2TB hard drive to my server, partitioned and formatted the drive.

Am I able to mount this drive to the folder /var/loggingdata123 so as far as the program is concerned nothing has changed, but i have just gained 2TB of hard drive space.

Am I correct in thinking this is possible or am I off the mark?

Thanks

Comment: It's all here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingANewHardDrive

Comment: I think you'd want to move your files to the new drive, then mount the drive as /var/logging/data123.....then that folder will have 2TB available (minus your current data), and the remainder of your filesystem wouldn't have your data consuming it's free space.

Comment: Pardon me, sir, but I could not understand your worries. Do you want your hard drive to be included in the system? What exactly do you want?

Comment: You may want to use [`logrotate`](//help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxLogFiles#Log_Rotation) to manage ever growing log files and delete old ones.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, that's absolutely possible. If you want to automount it, proceed as follows:

1. Execute `sudo blkid` to get the UUID of the partition you want to mount. This will give some lines like this

   ```
   /dev/sda1: UUID="0cde5cf9-b15d-4369-b3b1-4405204fd9ff" TYPE="ext4"
   ```

   Using the UUID instead of the device file name `sda1` makes this entry more consistent in case you choose to install another drive in the same machine, which will have another UUID, but may receive the device file name the current drive now has

   (Windows analogy: If you plug in one USB stick, it may receive the drive letter `F:`, if you remove it and plug another, this other one will most likely get `F:` instead. If you now plug the first stick again, it will receive another letter, e.g. `G:`, so you can't rely on that).

   Find out which one is your new drive (`sudo parted -l` gives some more information on the partition). Best open a text editor and copy and paste it there, so you'll have it at hand.
2. Mount the hard drive somewhere, e.g. in `/mnt/logs`:

   ```
   sudo mkdir /mnt/logs
   sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt/logs #Replace XY by the actual value
   ```
3. Move the existing log files to the new hard drive and check if there are any files remaning (files starting with a `.` will not be moved by this)

   ```
   sudo mv /var/logging/data123/* /mnt/logs
   ls -Al /var/logging/data123 #Shouldn't print any files, else move them also
   ```
4. Unmount the drive

   ```
   sudo umount /mnt/logs
   sudo rmdir /mnt/logs
   ```
5. Open the file `/etc/fstab` with a rooted text editor, e.g. with `sudo nano /etc/fstab` and add the following line at the end:

   ```
   UUID=<uuid> /var/logging/data123 <format> defaults 0 2
   ```

   Of course, replace `<uuid>` with the partitions UUID and `<format>` with the partition format you chose, e.g. `ext4`. Save the file (When using nano, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>) and exit the editor (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>)
6. Have the system automount the drive and check whether it worked:

   ```
   sudo mount -a
   mount #This will print a list of mounted drives, your new entry should be here
   ```

From now on, the drive will be mounted in `/var/logging/data123` on each boot automatically.